# How can I recompile my application.css.scss.erb asset after adding a new item to a collection in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails application which allows admin users to add colors to a collection dynamically, and then apply those colors to a post via a reference to the color and a css class.

In my application.css.scss.erb file I have the following code:

```
<% Color.all.each do |color| %>
    .theme-<%= color.name %>{
        color: <%= color.text_color %>;
        background: <%= color.hex_code %>;
        border-top-color: <%= color.hex_code %>;
    }
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I am going through all colors in the Colors collection and creating a specific css class for each one to be applied in the view of my posts.

Each post has a reference to a color in the Colors collection, and therefore in my Post view I apply the class like so:

```
<div id="post-header" class="theme-<%= @post.color.name %>">
    <h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
    <%= link_to image_tag('post_header_image.png'), post_path(@post) %>
</div>
```

I would like it so that an admin user can dynamically add a new color to the Colors collection via a form, and then have the application.css.scss.erb file compile automatically so that any new color classes can be applied right away, without having to manually refresh or update the application.css.scss.erb file.

The problem is that when I dynamically add a new Color to the color collection, my application.css.scss.erb file does not recompile and therefore the new color class is not created, so the actual color styles do not show up in my post view.

Is there any way to force rails to recompile my application.css.scss.erb file after adding a new color to the Colors collection?

Otherwise, is there a better way to handle dynamic styles and classes in Rails?

Answer (score -1):

Just a easy solution, if you just want to change colour of this div use the style tag?

```
<div id="post-header" style="<%= @post.color.name.present? ? "color: #{@post.color.name};" : "" %>">
  ...
</div>
```

If you aren't using standard colours, you can store the hex code in the database as another column and then have a extra # before the colour variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a more efficient solution that involves reusable classes. That way I don't have to include a lot of inline styles into one page. There will be some pages (e.g. the page with ALL Posts) that have to use many different colors, so using inline styles would just be too much.